# Why doesn't the `window.onerror` getter trigger when an uncaught error occurs?

Tags: javascript, window, descriptor, onerror

I want to interceptor the `window.onerror` which user defined, and get the error parameters info to do some analysis. The following is a part of the interceptor code:

```
const userError = window.onerror;
delete window.onerror;

const errorFn = (...args) => {
  // some code to collect args info
  if (userError) {
    userError.apply(window, args)
  }
}

Object.defineProperty(window, 'onerror', {
  get() {
    console.log('ONERROR GETTER');
    return errorFn
  },
  set() {
    // ... don't care
  }
})
```

However, the getter would not execute when an error occurs, such as calling window.abcdefg() which does not actually exist in window. Additionally, it does not print the identifier "ONERROR GETTER", which seems strange to me ...

I have shared my question and requested help. It is currently understood that the DOM is not a standard JavaScript object, and the behavior of onerror is not defined in the specification.

Now, I am sharing my question and hoping to receive more opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Why do you need `Object.defineProperty()`? Just wrap your "interceptor" around the user's event handler, and reassign it like so:

```js
const userError = window.onerror;
window.onerror = (...args) => {
  // some code to collect args info
  userError?.apply(window, args)
}
```

---

*I'm going to give a highly **speculative** answer based on my own tests because I couldn't find much information from browser source code, MDN documentation, or the HTML spec*:

So as you probably know, `onerror` is an attribute event listener, which enables you to conveniently get and set an event handler for "error" events, instead of using `addEventListener()`.

But did you know that the `onerror` property of `window` is by default an accessor property, meaning its descriptor defines getters and setters rather than a straightforward value. We can confirm this by inspecting `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "onerror")`, and this seems to be consistent across browsers.

So, this actually might hint towards how `window.onerror` implements attaching the event listener to `window`. That is, the `set()` accessor of `onerror` effectively just calls `addEventListener()` on the new value, and `removeEventListener()` on the old value, but in native code. However, we can easily reimplement this behavior in JavaScript like so:

```js
// For the sake of interactivity, I'm showing 'onclick'
let value = undefined;
Object.defineProperty(window, 'onclick', {
  get() {
    return value;
  },
  set(newValue) {
    console.log("new click handler"); // proof that our set() works
    window.removeEventListener('click', value);
    value = newValue;
    window.addEventListener('click', value);
  }
});

// demo
window.onclick = () => console.log("hello");
document.body.click();
window.onclick = () => console.log("world");
document.body.click();
```

So what does this entail? Well it means that when the window receives an "error" event (or any other attribute event), the browser isn't performing some special case to call `window.onerror()`. Instead, the browser likely uses the same logic as running event handlers attached directly with `addEventListener()`. In other words, the browser never actually accesses `window.onerror`, and that's why your `get()` accessor doesn't execute and `"ONERROR GETTER"` isn't printed.

This also explains how attribute event listeners respect definition order when multiple event listeners of the same type are defined; attribute event listeners are essentially just syntactic sugar for calling `addEventListener()`.

As a result, if you're overriding the descriptor with `Object.defineProperty()`, you will need to write something similar to the code above to preserve the semantics of `onerror`. **However**, see the TL;DR for how you can achieve what you probably want much more simply.

Comment: "TL;DR: Why do you need Object.defineProperty()? Just wrap your "interceptor" around the user's event handler..."

Because I don't know which script, mine or the user's, will be executed first or second, if I simply reassign a value, my script will be overwritten and won't execute if the user-defined error handler runs after my script.

Comment: Thank you for your answer has given me some ideas. If you're interested, could you help me review the [PR](https://github.com/HuolalaTech/page-spy/pull/7) code? Actually, this question comes from the `PageSpy` open source project that I'm maintaining. PageSpy is a tool similar to Google Devtools that allows remote debugging of web pages. 

Comment: @Blucas I left a comment about a potential issue.

Comment: @Blucas Also if my answer helped you with your issue, I would appreciate it if you marked it as the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who needs to interceptor the user defined `window.onerror`, following is a solution:

```
export default class ErrorPlugin implements PageSpyPlugin {
  public name = 'ErrorPlugin';

  public static hasInitd = false;

  public onCreated() {
    if (ErrorPlugin.hasInitd) return;
    ErrorPlugin.hasInitd = true;

    this.onUncaughtError();
    this.onResourceLoadError();
    this.onUnhandledRejectionError();
  }

  private onUncaughtError() {
    const userErr = window.onerror;
    // @ts-ignore
    const isConfigurable = delete window.onerror;
    if (!isConfigurable) {
      window.onerror = (...args) => {
        ErrorPlugin.sendMessage(args[4]);
        if (userErr) {
          userErr.apply(window, args);
        }
      };
      return;
    }

    let errorHandler: (this: Window, ev: ErrorEvent) => any;
    Object.defineProperty(window, 'onerror', {
      // Normally, users would simply capture errors by assigning to 'window.onerror',
      // but to avoid conflicts with the logic of other libraries, we specify
      // 'configurable' as false here.
      configurable: false,
      enumerable: true,
      get() {
        return errorHandler;
      },
      set(fn: OnErrorEventHandler) {
        window.removeEventListener('error', errorHandler);
        errorHandler = (e: ErrorEvent) => {
          ErrorPlugin.sendMessage(e.error?.stack || e.message);
          fn?.apply(window, [
            e.message,
            e.filename,
            e.lineno,
            e.colno,
            e.error,
          ]);
        };
        window.addEventListener('error', errorHandler);
      },
    });
    window.onerror = userErr;
  }

  private onResourceLoadError() {
    // ...
  }

  private onUnhandledRejectionError() {
    // ...
  }

  public static sendMessage(data: any) {
    // ...
  }
}
```